# MissingReferenceException when reloading scene using hotkey

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I've got a simple fade in/out coroutine setup for when a level is loaded/completed. It looks like this:

```cs
Image panel = GameObject.FindWithTag("FadePanel").GetComponent<Image>();
for (float o = 1; o > 0; o -= 0.05f) {
    var colour = panel.color;
    colour.a = o;
    panel.color = colour;
    yield return null;
}
```

The for loop is reversed for the fade out routine.

This code works fine when loading a new level, even loading the same level after it has been completed, which does nothing different from reloading. However, my debug accelerator F3 + A which reloads the current level causes a MissingReferenceException to be thrown when setting the image's colour.

The image is part of the player prefab which I load into the scene beforehand.

This is the code I think is relevant (Assume all coroutine calls are correct):

```cs
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetKey(/*F3 + A*/)) {
        FadeAndLoad(currentLevel);
    }
    if (/*Touching end box*/) {
        FadeAndLoad(nextLevel);
    }
}

IEnumerator FadeAndLoad(string nextFile) {
    // Fade out loop
    LoadLevel(nextFile);
}

IEnumerator LoadLevel(string levelFile) {
    currentLevel = levelFile;
    SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(1);
    // Wait for loading to complete.
    Scene levelScene = SceneManager.CreateScene("Level");
    // Do some stuff with the file
    SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(Instantiate(PlayerObject, /*Data from the file*/), levelScene);
    // Do some more stuff with the file
    SceneManager.SetActiveScene(levelScene);
    SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(1);
    // Fade in loop
}
```

Comment: Are you reloading the scene in the middle of the coroutine? Maybe the null reference is on the coroutine of the scene before the loading and not on the new one?

Comment: Could it be, that when you press F3 + A `FadeAndLoad(currentLevel)` gets called multiple times, not just once? Try replacing your `if (/*F3 + A*/)`with `if (InputGetKeyDown(KeyCode.F3) && InputGetKey(KeyCode.A))`

Comment: Yes, that was it. I'll edit my question to make this make more sense.